# use phonegap+jquery mobile load the external link,this history.back not work?

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova

i use phonega+jquerymobile develop a program. phonegap start with a local page.i need load some external page. so ,i use

```
$.mobile.changePage("some url");
```

to load the external page.when user navigation in the external page.could not use `history.back();`to back prev page. the program liks be crash and exit.
BTW,i use logcat found a ERR msg:

```
E/Web Console(334): SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent. at     
file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery.mobile-1.0.js:3536
In line 3536 of jquery.mobile-1.0.js: history.replaceState( state, document.title, href );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a hack. I found no other way to get around this issue in my app, so  I wrapped it:

```
history.replaceState( state, document.title, href );
```

into

```
try{history.replaceState( state, document.title, href );}catch(e){}
```

This discards the error, and the app still behaved. Use it at your own peril.